# First Order Logic: Unification of positive and negative literals

Tags: algorithm

While unifying two literals, can we unify a positive and negative literal. For e.g, *p(x) with ~P(A)*?

Is this unifiable using the substitution {x/A}. Russel & Norvig textbook doesn't say anything about unifying positive and negative literals while [slides](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse341/03au/slides/Prolog3/sld005.htm) from University of Toronto  says it is possible.